# Calculating Base Address of a Segment (Intel 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I know that, Physical Address = Segment Address x 10h + offset

Suppose, physical address of a memory location is 33330 H and the offset is 1111 H. To find the segment address, (33330 - 1111)/10 = 3221.

Now, if do the calculation for the physical address, 3221 x 10h + 1111 = 33321 which is not 33330.

Why is that so? Is my process correct?

Comment: It is not possible for an offset of 1111H to address location 33330H -- bottom hex digit of the address comes (only) from the offset, so they must be the same.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Dodd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always need possible physical address.
Segment physical address must be paragraph aligned: `n%10h=0`.

Here, `33330h-1111h=32219h` linear address

but you have to take `32210h` (possible physical address) or Logical Address= `3221:0009`

So, `(33330h - 1111h)/10h = 3221h` segment register value (segment base right shifted by 4).